# Django model form labels not working

Tags: python, html, django, forms, web

I'm using a model form in django 1.9 but label marks aren't generate while widget yes. Don't know why but something is going wrong.

Regards in advances,

This is py files:

model.py :

```
class Account(models.Model):
     pseudo = models.CharField(_('pseudo'), max_length=100)
     password = models.CharField(_('password'), max_length=42)
     email = models.EmailField(_('email'), null=True)
     def __str__(self):
         return self.pseudo
```

form.py :

```
class AccountForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('pseudo', 'password', 'email')
        labels = {
            'pseudo': _('Pseudo'),
            'password': _('Password'),
            'email': _('Email'),
        }
        widgets = {
            'pseudo': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
            }),
            'password': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
            }),
            'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
            }),
        }
```

view.py :

```
def signup(request):
    AccountFormSet = AccountForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if AccountFormSet.is_valid():
            AccountFormSet.save()
    return render(request, 'account/signup.html', {'formset': AccountFormSet})
```

signup.html :

```
{% for form in formset %}
   <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ form }}
      </div>
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

output is :

```
<input class="form-control" id="id_pseudo" maxlength="100" name="pseudo" type="text">
<input class="form-control" id="id_password" maxlength="42" name="password" type="password">
<input class="form-control" id="id_email" maxlength="254" name="email" type="email">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variable names are confusing. You refer to formsets but you are not using formsets anywhere. I would suggest changing the view as follows:

```
def signup(request):
    form = AccountForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    return render(request, 'account/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

Then in your template, you are looping through the form's fields, so change the variables there as well.

If you want to include the label tag, you need to explicitly include `{{ field.label_tag }}`. It would be a good idea to include `{{ field.errors }}` as well. For example:

```
{% for field in form %}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      {{ field.errors }}
      {{ field.label_tag }}
      {{ field }}
    </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

See the docs on [rendering fields manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst you've called the variable a form_set, it isn't actually a formset, its still just your single form.

```
AccountFormSet = AccountForm()
```

So you're not iterating over a set of forms, the form's iterator will iterate over the fields. So either include the label or just remove the for loop

```
{% for field in formset %}
   <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ field.label_tag }}
        {{ field }}
      </div>
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

```
   <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
          <form>{{ form }}</form>
      </div>
   </div>
```